# NuxtJS - how to disable route load/render?

Tags: nuxt.js

NuxtJS is rendering/loading the page every time. I want to have the page content just hidden or shown. not to reload it each time. i looked in the documentation but i can't find anything regarding this.
How can i do it?

Comment: May I know what do you mean by "rendering/loading the page every time"? The layout is always rendered for once, it is the page that gets loaded each time you change the URL.  Moreover, why you want to load all the page contents in a single go? I mean why you want to implement any structure like this? Please explain further for me to help you out.

Comment: I'm creating an Electron app which uses Nuxt.js. I have a map in one page and i don't want it to reload every time i switch pages. I want it to load just once.

Comment: Move that map to the layout then. It will load for once only.